# How to detect test suite and groups?

Tags: php, phpunit, automated-tests

In a `setUp` method of an abstract `TestCase`, I'd like to detect some basic information about the test that is currently running:

1. Name of the test suite?
2. Which group(s) the test belongs to?

Can you tell me how can I get these information in PHPUnit?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your nr.2:

You can take a look at `\PHPUnit_Util_Test` or `\Phpunit\Util\Test` and you will find the `getGroups($className, $methodName = '')`

To make use of it in PHPUnit 5.6:

```
/**
 * Is test in group
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isTestClassInGroup($groupName)
{
    foreach (PHPUnit_Util_Test::getGroups(static::class) as $index => $group) {
        if (stripos($group, $groupName) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```